# How Do I GET a StreamResponseBody and save it as a ZIP file using Powershell

Tags: powershell, get, zip, httpwebresponse

I am trying to extract a streaming response from a standard http GET call using PowerShell.

I tried to do something like using this `Invoke-RestMethod` method, such as:

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method GET -Headers $headers -Body
```

and then tried doing various things like accessing the streaming response in this way:

```
$Stream.Write($response.Content)
```

or

```
$Stream.Write($response.RawContentStream)
```

but nothing works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, I found out the following command does both the call and the response along with allowing you to save the result to a file directly. This surprised me because the response is a multipart record that includes headers and other data, not just the chunked file in the stream. But the folks at MS apparently knew that 99% of the time with a chunked reply, the user only wants to save the streamed chunks of data into the file, without the other response header data.

```
  $Response = Invoke-WebRequest @Params -Headers $headers -outfile $TempZipFileName
```

The key here is using the `Invoke-WebRequest` call with the `-outfile` option. This saved me a lot of headache and was super simple to use.

Comment: Fortunately the Web Response contained the zip file you wanted. If you want to write arbitrary files to an in-memory zip stream without intermediate files, you can use `Add-ZipEntry` from [ZipFunctions.ps1](https://github.com/mossrich/PowershellRecipes/blob/master/ZipFunctions.ps1).